# Call Python Script from VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel

I'm having a problem calling python scripts from vba in Excel. I read other threads that addressed the same problem, but when I run the code, a Python screen flashes and then disappears. FYI, I downloaded python 3.6.5 for Windows 10 and added it to PATH. Can someone let me know why the screen flashes and what I can do to solve it? Thanks

```
Sub Run_python()

Dim Ret_Val
Dim args As String

args = "C:\Users\opera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Tools\scripts\db2pickle.py"
Ret_Val = Shell("C:\Users\opera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" & " " & args, vbNormalFocus)

If Ret_Val = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't run python script!", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: can you add some `input()` statement at the end of your script? when the script finishes the window closes.

Comment: for anyone else that stumbles on this page, xlwings is a good extension that can simplify the manipulation of xl sheets with python functions

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what exactly would the input() statement look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen flashes and returns quickly because the program either failed or ran that fast to completion

Have you tried to run it from the command line to see what is happening?

If that runs fine, you can force the command window to stay open so you can read what's happening when you use python from the Shell command

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "C:\Users\opera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" & " " & args, vbNormalFocus)

/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K 
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates 
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Comment: I replaced the Ret_val=... line with your solution, and it brought up the command window, but I also get the message saying "Couldn't run python script" because apparently my return value was 0. Does that matter at all, and if not I can get rid of the Ret_Val variable?

Comment: You should be able to check `%ERRORLEVEL%` on its return. You don't need return value unless you are tracking how your script is exiting

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below as suggested:

```
Dim RetVal
args = """C:\Users\something\Desktop\md\test.py"""
RetVal = Shell("C:\Python37\python.exe " & " " & args)
If RetVal = 0 Then
   MsgBox "Couldn't run python script!", vbOKOnly
End If
```

After running the script the command window was just flashing.
So, I just added input('Press any key to exit') statement as the last line of my python script and now the window stays.