# I want to run a python script as a function in VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am pretty new to this.
I am trying to get a python script to run through excel
I need to use excel because that is what the people I work with understand.
I'm stuck because my python script works but I can't get it to work in VBA ideally I need it to run as a function one that I can run on a nearby cell just like any other formula.

my python script is pretty basic and just returns one output for every input.

I know this won't do what I need it to do but I'm not sure why it just pops up the command window and doesn't do anything else.

```vb
Sub runpython()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = """Python path"""

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

Comment: The question has been asked before: 1. [How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba), 2. [Is there a way to call a Python code in Excel-VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410316/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-python-code-in-excel-vba), 3. [Running a python script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060097/running-a-python-script-from-vba), 4. [Call Python Script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805511/call-python-script-from-vba).

Comment: One more example that focuses on returning a value from the python script: [Return result from Python to Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39517658/14608750)

Comment: What's in your Python script file?  You say it "returns one output for every input", but what are the inputs?

Comment: Inputs are a string about 30 characters long, the python file is just a series of if statements that return different options based on the character in different positions.