# Is there a way to run a python script to in excel to update a cell range?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a web **scraper** script in python that clicks and downloads a csv file from a website.

I would like to:

1. Pass a parameter from excel to trigger the python script based on user selection
2. trigger the download/web **scraper** script from Excel and then populate the cell range concerned based on the downloaded file

Welcome to other solutions other than what I have now.

Comment: The question has been asked before: 1. [How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18135551/14608750), 2. [Is there a way to call a Python code in Excel-VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45410316/14608750), 3. [Running a python script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48060097/14608750), 4. [Call Python Script from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50805511/14608750). 5. [Return result from Python to Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39516875/14608750)

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your python code should read your excel spreadsheet and act upon the changes. Might want to check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html. A more straightforward solution might exist, thou.